# auth is not available in module

Tags: python, web2py

I have a web2py application where I have written various modules which hold business logic and database related stuff. In one of the files I am trying to access `auth.settings.table_user_name` but it doesn't work and throws and error as `global name 'auth' is not defined`. If I write the same line in controller, it works. But I want it to be accessed in module file. Please suggest how do I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model file, where you define `auth`:

```
from gluon import current

auth = Auth(db)
current.auth = auth
```

Then in a module:

```
from gluon import current

def some_function():
    auth = current.auth
    ....
```

For more details, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules.

Comment: I am trying same thing and getting this error:----  *** AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'auth'

Comment: The code that is attempting to access `current.auth` must be running before the assignment of `current.auth = auth` has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a very similar error ("name 'auth' is not defined"). Had to add `from django.contrib import auth` at the top of views.py and it worked.